# 301 редирект через htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скорректировать файл .htaccess, чтобы:

1) При обращении к [http://сайт.ru](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) и [http://www.сайт.ru](http://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) открывался [https://www.сайт.ru](https://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) 
2) При обращении к [https://сайт.ru](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) открывался [https://www.сайт.ru](https://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) 
3) При обращении к [http://www.сайт.ru/robots.txt](http://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru/robots.txt) этот адрес открывался без редиректа.

Текущий .htaccess выглядит следующим образом:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

В первом перенаправлении была ошибка.

Необходимо было выполнять редирект на https, был на http.

Comment: Необходимо было выполнять редирект на https, был на http.

Comment: Понял, а как настроить исключение для страницы http://www.сайт.ru/robots.txt, чтобы она открывалась без редиректа?

Comment: С данной конфигурацией, как и с предыдущей, переадресация не будет происходить. Так как доменное имя `www.сайт.ru` не удовлетворяет ни одному из условий  `^сайт.ru$` и `^сайт.ru$`.

Comment: Мой изначальный вопрос был с ошибкой, т.к. при описанной Вами конфигурации не происходит редиректа со страницы <code>http:// www.сайт.ru/123</code> на страницу     https:// www.сайт.ru/123, а мне нужно именно это.

Comment: Добавил в ответ еще одно условие с перенаправлением

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. Только теперь необходимо добавить исключение для адреса HTTP:// WWW.сайт.ru/robots.txt, чтобы не было перенаправления на HTTPS.

Comment: Добавил исключение в ответ

Comment: Всё работает, большое спасибо.